# Docker container - write CSV from PHP script adding permissions

Tags: php, docker, csv, chmod

Hi All hope someone can help!

I have created a php script which does a number of cURL checks on URLS the results of which I want to write to a csv file. When I run my php script on command line or when hosted on a lampt server it will run the script fine and write to the csv. However when I build a container and run the container it is giving me a a 403 error [image]

When I run it on kubernetes I get the same page aswell.

In my dockerfile I think I have given permission but this may be where my problem lies:[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://pimylifeup.com/chmod-777/#:~:text=An%20unauthorized%20user%20could%20use,any%20user%20on%20the%20system.  You're not recursively chmodding, so it only affects /var/www/html, not the contents of src/.  I'm not convinced the issue is the filesystem permissions - check apache logs

Comment: Thank you looked it up I added -R before 777 on line 3.